# Import driftyco's premuim ionicons into ionic2 application

Tags: css, angular, ionic2, ionicons

GitHub Link: [github.com](https://github.com/eshk12/Parabi/tree/DB-LINKED/)
I have found Driftyco's ionicons repository, And I would like to use it.

I have download it and import the files `ionicons.css` and folder `fonts` into my folder `/src/assets`, And insert the css file inside `/src/index.html`.

I have also change the `fonts` dir in the css file to the correct location.
When I write this in my code `<i class="icon ion-home"></i>` nothing happen.

It's seem that's not recognized it.

Please help :)

Comment: you should already have ionicons in your default ionic project once you start it...

Comment: its a premium pack

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462885/add-custom-icon-in-ionic-2

Comment: I'm talking about this specific pack: http://ionicons.com/

Comment: It looks like you followed all the correct steps from here but need to see your code to help you out. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons#getting-started