# How to use custom icons in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

```
<ion-tab [root]="geralTabRoot" [rootParams]="enterprise" tabTitle="Geral" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
```

I have this tab using the tabIcon, How can I use a custom icon?
I already created the SVG pic

Comment: Please take a look at [this amazing post](https://yannbraga.com/2017/06/28/how-to-use-custom-icons-on-ionic-3/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Custom Icon in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462885/add-custom-icon-in-ionic-2)