# ionic2: how can I set my Icons as ionic icons

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2: I have my Icons and I want to set them as we set Ionic icons:

```
<ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
```

what should I do to use my icons, I don't want to use online Icons I want to use my icons

Comment: here is the stack overflow link  to answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462885/add-custom-icon-in-ionic-2

Comment: @AnilMaurya Is there is any video to clarify it?

Comment: here is the another blog link , please try to read it properly i'm sure you will understand 
https://yannbraga.com/2017/06/28/how-to-use-custom-icons-on-ionic-3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Custom Icon in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462885/add-custom-icon-in-ionic-2)

Comment: Follow @adjwilli answer.