# ionic2: Custom SVG Icons

Tags: svg, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2 I want to use my icons as I use Ionic Icons I've seen this link: [custom ionic icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462885/add-custom-icon-in-ionic-2)

but I Can't Follow the instruction and I can't understand what is the SVG icons, I don't want to make Icons I have Icons as images and I want to use It, can anyone help me!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `.svg` to `.png`. Add this to your `app.scss` file

```
ion-icon {
    &[class*="appname-"] { 
        mask-size: contain;
        mask-position: 50% 50%;
        mask-repeat: no-repeat;
        background: currentColor;
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
    } 
    &[class*="appname-customicon1"] {
        mask-image: url(../assets/img/customicon1.png);
    } 
}
```

Uses

```
<ion-icon name="appname-customicon1"></ion-icon>
```

Credit: [adjwilli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272011/adjwilli).

Comment: I have warning that tags: (mask-size, mask-position, mask-repeat and mask-image ) --> [scss] Unknown property

Comment: in app.scss file

Comment: I can't upload image in the comments but it is not an error it is just a warning that scss not know such these tags

Comment: the icon doesn't appear