# tabs and tab custom icon in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-tabs

i am building an ionic application in which i am using ionic tabs at the bottom for navigation for the whole application.. i want to add custom **svg** as tabs icon. i don't  know how can i do this but if there is any solution kindly provide the link or code or any reference of the document.

hi there!! i am building an ionic application in which i am using ionic tabs at the bottom for navigation for the whole application.. i want to add custom **svg** as tabs icon. i don't  know how can i do this but if there is any solution kindly provide the link or code or any reference of the document.

and i also want to add avatar in ionic tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can firstly add custom ionic icon:[Add Custom Icon in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462885/add-custom-icon-in-ionic-2)

then use tabIcon attribute in the ion-tab:

```
<ion-tab [root]="chatRoot" tabTitle="Chat" tabIcon="custom-icon"></ion-tab>
```

Answer (score 7):

It's so simple and easy. You just have you use this CSS/SCSS for your custom icon.

```
ion-icon {
&[class*="custom-"] {
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    $sz: 20px;
    width: $sz;
    height: $sz;
} // custom icons
&[class*="pin"][ng-reflect-is-active="true"] {
    background: url("../assets/imgs/custom-icons/pin_on.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: contain;
}//in case of active
&[class*="pin"][ng-reflect-is-active="false"] {
    background: url("../assets/imgs/custom-icons/pin_off.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: contain;
}//in case of inactive
&[class*="stars"] {
    background: url("../assets/imgs/custom-icons/stars.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

}

and this will be your HTML content. I have given here two examples, one for  one for normal

```
<ion-tab [root]="home" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="custom-pin"></ion-tab>

// another example

<ion-icon name="custom-stars" color="primary"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, it was WAY more helpful than the chosen one, thanks Arindam!

Answer (score 0):

First you download your required font family.  than give path in app.css like :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  src: url("../assets/font/Flaticon.eot");
  src: url("../assets/font/Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("../assets/font/Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
       url("../assets/font/Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("../assets/font/Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

also add this css for every which you want in your app.css

```
.flaticon-stadium:before ,
.ion-ios-flaticon-stadium:before ,
.ion-ios-flaticon-stadium-outline:before ,
.ion-md-flaticon-stadium:before ,
.ion-md-flaticon-stadium-outline:before  {
  font-family: Flaticon;
  content: '\f101';
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

and on your html tabs code here

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Facilities" tabIcon="flaticon-stadium"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```